# Desktop won't load

Tags: 11.10, unity, login

I installed Unity 5.0 to test on my 11.10 setup and I've just removed it recently. Restarting the computer, I can't logon to my desktop now. I insert my password, then a black screen comes up and then it goes back to the login screen.

Installations

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:unity-team/stages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Removal

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:unity-team/stages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try booting your system in 'recovery mode' do the fsck option. After it's done press enter and select booting to root shell with networking (netroot) put in
`apt-get install unity`
If unity is still installed it won't do anything, if it's not installed anymore it will reinstall it.
You should also do `dpkg-reconfigure unity` and `dpkg-reconfigure gdm`.
This helped me with a similar problem on 'Lubuntu', where lxde (the desktop environment) wouldn't load.